# Spacing in entrylist moves the adjacent block

Tags: spacing, cv, friggeri-cv

Small question here. I'm using a template which I'm not to familiar with, and kind of newbie to.
So the part of the code I'm having trouble with

```
\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {RELAP \\ SIMPLER \\ XX   
    }
    {Nuclear Safety, Neutronic and Termohidraulics Analysis}
    {}
    {\emph{I can use several computational tools for engineering analysis. I've used codes such as  and programed implementations with the Point Kinetic Equations, }}
```

The output is

[image]

As you can see the "Beginning of Nuclear Safety..." follows the last line of the other block, to the left.
And I would like the list on the left, that is " RELAP SIMPLER .."" to be at the left of the \emph text

[image]

Without touching the title.

I think this problem is related to the environment and no to the format. The format of the template is the following

```
\ProvidesClass{friggeri-cv}[2012/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}
```

´

```
%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%
[stuff]


%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

I know that this can be done with `minipage` and `tabular`, but that generates other issues of spacing and such, and just being able to solve this in a straight forward way, implementing the structures the template already uses would be great.
Thanks in advance

```
Format file-----------> friggeri-cv.cls

\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1.5, 4.33)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[style=verbose, maxnames=99, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1\par}
\DeclareFieldFormat[report]{title}{#1\par}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \usebibmacro{journal+issuetitle}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{pages}%
    \newunit%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{misc}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{booktitle}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{note}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printlist{location}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{report}{%
  \printfield{title}%
  \newblock%
  \printnames{author}%
  \par%
  \newblock%
  {%
    \footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}\itshape%
    \printfield{type}%
    \setunit{\space}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{year}%
    \newunit%
  }
  \par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}
}

\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \small\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{#3\space}#1%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}
    {}%
}

\newcommand{\printbibsection}[2]{
  \begin{refsection}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type={#1}, title={#2}, heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsection}
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{chronological}{
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}
  \sort[direction=descending]{\field{month}}
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Other tweaks %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[left=6.1cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Main file CV.tex

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\header{XX}{XX}
       {XX}


% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{about}
    XX
  \section{languages}
    XX
  \section{programming}
      XX             
\end{aside}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {RELAP \\ SIMPLER 
    }
    {Nuclear Safety, Neutronic and Termohidraulics Analysis}
    {}
    {\emph{text text text}}
  \entry
    {06–08 2007}
    {LIP6/CNRS, Paris}
    {Research Internship.}
    {\emph{Kernels in real world networks.}}
\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: should that word "adjent" in the title be "adjacent"?  (i think so, but don't have time to decipher the code to make sure.)

Comment: And what are `\headingfont`  and `headercolor`? It would be nice to have a compilable Minimal Working Example, so that we can test.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want something like this? I took several fragments of your code, and corrected some inconsistencies (and typos). I prefer to use the `tabularx` environment, but I don't see why you set `\tabcolsep` to 0pt. Finally the alignment problem for blocks can be solved using `\break` instead of `\\`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{headercolor}{black}
\let\headingfont\sffamily
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
\noindent\sffamily\tabularx{\textwidth}{@{}p{25mm} > {\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X@{}}
}{%
  \endtabularx
}
%

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1  &
    \textbf{\headingfont\color{headercolor}#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3\break}%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {RELAP \break SIMPLER \break XX
    }
    {Nuclear Safety, Neutronic and Thermohydraulics Analysis}
    {}
    {\emph{I can use several computational tools for engineering analysis. I've used codes such as  and programmed implementations with the Point Kinetic Equations, }}
    \end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, well thank you very much for your time patience and efforts, yeah this solvs it

Answer (score 1):

I know that this topic is quite old and you said

> I know that this can be done with `minipage` and `tabular`, but that
>   generates other  issues of spacing and such, and just being able to
>   solve this in a straight forward way, implementing the structures the
>   template already uses would be great. Thanks in advance

but I had a similar issue and was able to solve it just fine with a `minipage`. I don't see any problem with the spacing, please correct me if I'm wrong. So for anybody who comes across this topic, having the same issue and like me is looking for a quick (and dirty) solution, try

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\header{XX}{XX}
       {XX}


% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{about}
    XX
  \section{languages}
    XX
  \section{programming}
      XX             
\end{aside}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
      {
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.15\textwidth}
            RELAP \\ SIMPLER
        \end{minipage}
     }
    {Nuclear Safety, Neutronic and Termohidraulics Analysis}
    {}
    {\emph{text text text}}
  \entry
    {06–08 2007}
    {LIP6/CNRS, Paris}
    {Research Internship.}
    {\emph{Kernels in real world networks.}}
\end{entrylist}


\end{document}
```

i.e. inside the first {}-brackets use a `minipage` with the content you want. Here, I took the code from the main file CV.tex the OP used. If you want it to be aligned with the text in `\emph{...}`, you could still add a `\valign{0.175cm}` (or something around that value) right in the `minipage`. Maybe you will have to play around with the `0.15\textwidth` as well, but still, I don't see any trouble with the spacing in my case.

Comparison:
[image: Without the minipage]

[image: Using a minipage]