# Blocks alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, line-breaking

I'm new with LaTeX, so to start I've downloaded a template of CV.
[image]

I want to do a newline in the left block, but the result that i obtain is this:
[image]

As you can see the two blocks are no more horizontally aligned.
How can i do?

Here is the code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
#1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
\textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3\\}%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

And here is the usage of the `\entry`:

```
\entry {2006--\\2011} {Diploma {\normalfont of High School, \\
Scientifico-Tecnologico}} {Liceo Scientifico Statale Aldo Moro, Reggio
Emilia} {\emph{grade: 94/100} }
```

I've found a question very similar to this [Spacing in entrylist moves the adjacent block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207352/spacing-in-entrylist-moves-the-adjacent-block) and I've proved to change `\\` with `\break` but it doesn't do nothing, or better it doesn't even create the new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template that you use basically uses a `tabular` table environment.  In the command `\entry`, the argument #1 is added as-is into this table.  Therefore, if argument #1 contains a line break `\\`, it adds a new line to the table.  So the solution is to encapsulate #1 in some way in the definition of `\entry`.  One idea is to use a `\parbox`, since a `\parbox` is already used for the second cell in the table.  For example:

```
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
\parbox[t]{2cm}{#1}&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
\textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize%\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}
      #3\\}%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

You can, of course, make the 2cm smaller, if you like.